# Unable to to see Required message on the radio buttons fields in the MVC.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a radio buttons field and I try tome make this field required. However, no matter what I try after I click the Submit button, no Required field message shows up on the page

Here is the radio button field

```
                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <div class="bisformdynamiclabel"></div>
                            <br />
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.BIS232Request.JSONData.OwnershipActivity.Ownership, "Yes", new { id = "OwnershipAnswer_true", onclick = "displayOwnershipFieldsRow(true)" })
                            <label for="OwnershipAnswer_true">Yes</label>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.BIS232Request.JSONData.OwnershipActivity.Ownership, "No", new { id = "OwnershipAnswer_false", onclick = "displayOwnershipFieldsRow(false)" })
                            <label for="OwnershipAnswer_false">No</label>
                        </div>
```

Here is the code in the Model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Yes or No for the Ownership")]
    public string Ownership { get; set; }
```

Other fields are validated without any issues. Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything actually displaying the messages. Specifically, you need something like:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BIS232Request.JSONData.OwnershipActivity.Ownership)
```

Or using the tag helper:

```
<span asp-validation-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.OwnershipActivity.Ownership"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help